# How do I split a string in C# based on letters and numbers

Tags: c#, regex, string

How can I split a string such as "Mar10" into "Mar" and "10" in c#? The format of the string will always be letters then numbers so I can use the first instance of a number as an indicator for where to split the string.

Comment: You don't have always exactly three characters, do you? Dec12, Jan5, Jul17 ...

Comment: Yes, in this case I do. 3 chars for date and 2 for year.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourString, "(\w+)(\d+)");
var month = match.Groups[0].Value;
var day = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not saying it directly, but from your example it seems are you just trying to parse a date.

If that's true, how about this solution:

```
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact("Mar10", "MMMdd", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date.Month);
    Console.WriteLine(date.Day);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourString, "([|A-Z|a-z| ]*)([\d]*)");
var month = match.Groups[1].Value;
var day = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
```

I tried Konrad's answer above, but it didn't quite work when I entered it into RegexPlanet.  Also the `Groups[0`] returns the whole string `Mar10`.  You want to start with `Groups[1]`, which should return `Mar` and `Groups[2]` should return `10`.

Answer (score 3):

```
char[] array = "Mar10".ToCharArray();
int index = 0;
for(int i=0;i<array.Length;i++)
{
   if (Char.IsNumber(array[i]){
      index = i;
      break;
   }
}
```

Index will indicate split position.