# Splitting string containing letters and numbers not separated by any particular delimiter in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, algorithm, nlp

Currently I am developing a web application to fetch Twitter stream and trying to create a natural language processing by my own.

Since my data is from Twitter (limited by 140 characters) there are many words shortened, or on this case, **omitted space**.

For example:

```
"Hi, my name is Bob. I m 19yo and 170cm tall"
```

Should be tokenized to:

```
- hi
- my
- name
- bob
- i
- 19
- yo
- 170
- cm
- tall
```

Notice that `19` and `yo` in `19yo` have **no space** between them. I use it mostly for extracting numbers with their units.

Simply, what I need is a way to 'explode' each tokens that has number in it by chunk of numbers or letters **without** delimiter.

`'123abc'` will be `['123', 'abc']`

`'abc123'` will be `['abc', '123']`

`'abc123xyz'` will be `['abc', '123', 'xyz']`

and so on.

What is the best way to achieve it in PHP?

---

I found something close to it, but it's C# and spesifically for day/month splitting. [How do I split a string in C# based on letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2362153/670623)

Comment: #just curious, why do you need extraction like that?

Comment: I could see doing this for dynamic slug creation, but it could also be done with just space/punctuation delimiting.

Comment: @chasing-death because the data source (twitter stream) has inconsistent writing

Comment: @Dutchie432: I can do nothing about delimiting, because I cannot dictate how people post their tweets

Comment: @Akhyar Amarullah: I know, but I was respinding to `Chasing Death`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [preg_split](http://de3.php.net/preg-split)

```
$string = "Hi, my name is Bob. I m 19yo and 170cm tall";
$parts = preg_split("/(,?\s+)|((?<=[a-z])(?=\d))|((?<=\d)(?=[a-z]))/i", $string);
var_dump ($parts);
```

When matching against the digit-letter boundary, the regular expression match must be zero-width. The characters themselves must not be included in the match. For this the [zero-width lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are useful.

http://codepad.org/i4Y6r6VS

Comment: Sorry, haven't obvisouly tested it. Didnt know codepad.org existed. Will make use of it now.

Comment: @d_inevitable I don't really get your later explanation. Does it means there is some condition your regex cannot do it correctly?

Comment: No I am just explaining what the previous problem was when having something like `[a-z]\d` as the letter-digit boundary. That expression would produce `['a', 2]` from `'ab12'`, because `b1` would be interpreted as the boundary and thus excluded.

Comment: Also remember cases like "Download Concrete5 CMS".

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

you extract numbers from string by using regexps, store them in an array, replace numbers in string with some kind of special character, which will 'hold' their position. and after parsing the string created only by your special chars and normal chars, you will feed your numbers from array to theirs reserved places.

just an idea, but imho might work for you.

EDIT:
try to run this short code, hopefully you will see my point in the output. (this code doesnt work on codepad, dont know why)

```
<?php
$str = "Hi, my name is Bob. I m 19yo and 170cm tall";
preg_match_all("#\d+#", $str, $matches);
$str = preg_replace("!\d+!", "#SPEC#", $str);

print_r($matches[0]);
print $str;
```

Comment: interesting, but also a little confusing to me.. could you give me some additional explanation?

Comment: answer edited, check it out. if you need more explanation, just ask, ill support whole solution after i get my sleep ;)