# How to split English letters, numbers and Chinese characters?

Tags: php, regex, string, explode

To better illustrate the question, I will state a couple of inputs together with the desired outputs:

- INPUT 1: **This中文5142**
- OUTPUT 1: **array('This', '中文', '5142')**
- INPUT 2: **This 中文,5142**
- OUTPUT 2: **array('This', '中文', '5142')**

So basically, the input string can either have white space or not, and the sequence of the English letters, numbers and Chinese characters is unknown and can occur more than once.

I found out this one that can do the job when there is no Chinese characters (reference: [Splitting string containing letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180730/splitting-string-containing-letters-and-numbers-not-separated-by-any-particular)):

```
$array = preg_split("/(,?\s+)|((?<=[a-z])(?=\d))|((?<=\d)(?=[a-z]))/i", $str);
```

I can roughly understand the above regular expression:

1. (,?\s+) - split by white spaces and so
2. (?<=[a-z])(?=\d) - if a number is right after a letter, split them
3. (?<=\d)(?=[a-z]) - if a letter is right after a number, split them

So I was thinking naively like this: I will need to do a total of 3 things:

1. if a number is right after a letter or Chinese character, split them
2. if a letter is right after a number or Chinese character, split them
3. if a Chinese character is right after a letter or number, split them

To achieve 1, I was thinking like this:

```
(?<=[a-z\x4E00-\x9FA5])(?=\d)
```

where \x4E00-\x9FA5 is to match Chinese characters. But this doesn't work!

Comment: Grab them one by one using `[a-zA-Z]*`, `[0-9]*` and `[^a-zA-Z0-9]*`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But do you mind writing down a complete regular expression? Thanks.

Comment: @ShellFish that won't work quite right for example #2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that in an explicit way, you can use:

```
$result = preg_split('~(?<!\p{Latin})(?=\p{Latin})|(?<!\p{Han})(?=\p{Han})|(?<![0-9])(?=[0-9])~u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

*(that splits the string on each boundary)*. Note that if you have only three kind of characters, you can remove one of the boundaries (the one you want).

If you want to remove white-spaces from the result, you can put all in a non-capturing group and add `\s*` at the beginning of the pattern.

However using `preg_match_all` may give the same result with less effort:

```
if (preg_match_all('~\p{Latin}+|\p{Han}+|[0-9]+~u', $str, $matches))
    $result = $matches[0];
```

The u modifier forces the regex engine to read the string as an UTF8 string.

Comment: Both methods work like a charm. Thanks a lot. But I may need a couple of minutes to understand the express :(