# How to merge two cells value and check with WHERE clause in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string which is combination of two cells from a mysql table

My strings are like this `user_ID = 100A, 100B, 100C ...`

My Mysql Table has cells value like thi `USER = 100, ID = A, ....`

SO I want to get result from the table using where clause like this

```
(SELECET * FROM table1 WHERE USER+ID = "100A" ORDER BY USER)
```

please tell me how to correctly use above query

Comment: What strings? where is your table format? what have you tried so far? why is there a + after USER? I highly doubt that this query works, btw SELECT* you have a typo.

Comment: `WHERE user =100 AND id="A"` ?

Comment: ^ above is better but can `WHERE concat(USER,ID) = "100A"` but this does not use indexes

Answer (score 0):

first you need to split string like this 100 and A [Check Output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb3d447be2a316c59b9f7b3c0d702a65e418825d). and then you can execute query. here is the example

```
<?php
  $string='100A';
  $parts = preg_split("/(,?\s+)|((?<=[a-z])(?=\d))|((?<=\d)(?=[a-z]))/i", $string);
  print_r($parts );
  //so you can execute query
  SELECET * FROM table1 WHERE USER = $parts[0]  and ID = $parts[1] ORDER BY USER
?>
```

[Reference to split string with details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180730/splitting-string-containing-letters-and-numbers-not-separated-by-any-particular)

Comment: If split than `$parts = preg_split("/\d+\K/", $string);`

Comment: @splash58 yes. you are right. at the bottom of my answer i have provide the reference to split in details